# How to compute several hashes at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, hash, md5, sha

I want to computes multiple hashes of the same file and save time by multiprocessing.

From what I see, reading a file from ssd is relatively fast, but hash computing is almost 4 times slower. If I want to compute 2 different hashes (md5 and sha), it's 8 times slower. I'd like to able to compute different hashes on different processor cores in parallel (up to 4, depending on the settings), but don't understand how I can get around GIL.

Here are is my current code (`hash.py`):

```
import hashlib
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

file = 'test/file.mov' #50MG file

def hash_md5(file):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    with open(file, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            md5.update(chunk)
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return md5.hexdigest()

def hash_sha(file):
    sha = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            sha.update(chunk)
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return sha.hexdigest()

def hash_md5_sha(file):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    sha = hashlib.sha1()
    with open(file, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            md5.update(chunk)
            sha.update(chunk)
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return md5.hexdigest(), sha.hexdigest()

def read_file(file):
    with open(file, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return
```

I did some tests and here are the results:

```
from hash import *
from timeit import timeit
timeit(stmt='read_file(file)',globals=globals(),number = 100)
1.6323043460000122
>>> timeit(stmt='hash_md5(file)',globals=globals(),number = 100)
8.137973076999998
>>> timeit(stmt='hash_sha(file)',globals=globals(),number = 100)
7.1260356809999905
>>> timeit(stmt='hash_md5_sha(file)',globals=globals(),number = 100)
13.740918666999988
```

This result should be a function, the main script will iterate through file list, and should check different hashes for different files (from 1 to 4). 
Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Comment: You can use the ```PoolProcessExecutor()``` method from the ```concurrent.futures``` class. I believe this will help you to achieve what you want. You can find more details of the library here: [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)

Comment: see also [Simultaneously calculate multiple digests (md5, sha256)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163747/simultaneously-calculate-multiple-digests-md5-sha256)

Answer (score 0):

As someone stated in the comments, you could use `concurrent.futures`. I've done few benchmarks and the most efficient way to do it was using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Here is an example:

```py
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
executor.map(hash_function, files)
executor.shutdown()
```

If you want to take a look at my benchmarks you can find them [here](https://pastebin.com/VjMPCaR5) and the results:

```
Total using read_file: 10.121980099997018
Total using hash_md5_sha: 40.49621040000693
Total (multi-thread) using read_file: 6.246223400000417
Total (multi-thread) using hash_md5_sha: 19.588415799999893
Total (multi-core) using read_file: 4.099713300000076
Total (multi-core) using hash_md5_sha: 14.448464199999762
```

I used 40 files of 300 MiB each for testing.

Comment: Thank you your reply and code examples. My results for SSD look promising, but same test on slow media is actually slower:
My guess the problem here is that random access on external HDD is causing lower average  read speed.
Is there any way to perform sequential reads but paralled hash computation? My results: https://pastebin.com/b6Cfiyp5

Comment: As I know hash algorithms are generally not made to be computed in a parallel manner. You could try to use a faster hashing library (hashlib is pretty slow as far as I know) and maybe a file I/O library that promises async operations. You can find an example here: [aiofile](https://github.com/mosquito/aiofile), but I did not test it.

Comment: I understand that computing of a single hash shouldn’t benefit from parallel processing, but multiple hashes at the same time are not a problem, right? My original idea was to compute sha and md5 hash at the same time in 2 different threads (or more threads, if more hashes are required), but I don’t understand how I can achieve it. I guess I need to start 2 (or more) python processes with multiprocessing module and somehow exchange the data with them? Or create a C library for this specific purpose and bind it to python?

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your code in this way:

```
from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
 
def hasher(filename, func):
    # how to use:
    # print(f'{hasher(filename, md5())}')
    # print(f'{hasher(filename, sha1())}')
    # print(f'{hasher(filename, sha256())}')
    value = func
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            value.update(chunk)
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return value.hexdigest()
```

For parallel hash calculation:

```
def multi_hash(filename, func):
    # how to use : print(f'{multi_hash(filename, [md5(), sha1(), sha256()])}')
    value = func
    with open(filename, mode='rb') as fl:
        chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while chunk:
            for v in value:
                v.update(chunk)
            chunk = fl.read(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    return [h.hexdigest() for h in value]
```

Comment: Proof-read your post, and fix the messed up indentation of function bodies. As is, it's not valid Python code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the cut and paste is no so friendly. Do you thinis better ?

Comment: Yep, looks OK now.